# Google map not visible in android tabs

Tags: android, google-maps, tabs

In my application i need to display Google map and i am using tabs. In this, it displays correctly in my MainActivity, from this i moved to DetailsActivity. From this, if i come back , the google map lost its focus. If i touch the view, then map visible.

i am using the following.

**xml**

```
 <fragment 
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
 />
```

**MainActivity**

```
 GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
     bounds=new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(33.66554145358971, -117.90573209524155),
                         new LatLng(33.668909956981885, -117.89749503135681));
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.categorymap);
                     GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
                     .image(image)
                     .positionFromBounds(bounds)
                     .transparency(0.1f)
                     .anchor(0.1f, 0.5f);
                     map.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);
      map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(f_lat, f_lang), 18)); 
      map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);



 map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener()
    {
    @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
   Intent intent=new Intent(getParent(),MapZoom_BigActivity.class);  
   Intent intent2=new Intent(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
   View view = MapTab.group.getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("notification",intent2).getDecorView();  
   MapTab.group.replaceView(view);
   return true;
                     }

                 });
```

**DetailsActivity**

```
   // i used the following code in my back button onclick
    MapTab.group.onBackPressed();
```

So, please guide me how to solve this.

Comment: "If i touch the view, then map visible" what does it means? explain more

Comment: when i come to that activity , the google map was not visible(shows only empty white screen), if i touch the map view, then map was loaded (map and markers are loaded)

Comment: then you need to called `setUpMapIfNeeded();` for your map load again in your activity `onResume()` and load `Marker` on `Setup();` method

Comment: yes , i am ready to do that. But,if i coming back , the activity onResume() was not called.

Comment: i tried to do that, but the map view was not loaded.

Comment: no no it's not possible.

Comment: `LocalActivityManager` has been deprecated for over three years. Feel free to use modern and supported tab implementations, such as a `ViewPager` with a tabbed indicator, or action bar tabs, or `FragmentTabHost`. Here is a sample project demonstrating the use of maps in pages of a `ViewPager`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager

Comment: @koti What OS version are you at? If lower version use SupportMapFragment

Answer (score 0):

To show the map in my application, I have:

```
        MapViewFragment mapView = MapViewFragment.newInstance();
        mapView.setRetainInstance(true);
```

You might want to call that in order to show the map view (not sure you need setRetainInstance).